# MySQL int column allows null but enters null as zero

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've looked around and have noticed a few people have had the same problem but their oversight doesn't seem to apply here.

I have a PHP function to add an array of values into a table. It first checks whether the values are empty and if so replaces them with `NULL`, in order to place a `null` in the table field. Each fields that I'm placing `null` into allows for `null` yet places a `0` there instead.

Here's some code:

```
public static function AddGame($array, $tId)
{
    global $db; // Bring DB into scope
    // Get IDs from particular names
    $locId = $array['fLocation'];
    // Ensure empty values are SQL null
    $hTeamId = "'{$array['fHomeTeam']}'";
    $vTeamId = "'{$array['fVisitTeam']}'";
    $hScore = "'{$array['fHomeScore']}'";
    $vScore = "'{$array['fVisitScore']}'";
    $hHoldFor = "'{$array['fHomeHoldFor']}'";
    $vHoldFor = "'{$array['fVisitHoldFor']}'";
    // Prepare row for insertion
    $row = "'','$tId','$locId',$hTeamId,$vTeamId,'{$array['fDate']}','{$array['fTime']}',$hScore,$vScore,'{$array['fGameType']}',$hHoldFor,$vHoldFor";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `game` VALUES($row)");
    if($stmt->execute()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I've debugged this function at various lines and have dumped the $row string and it shows this, which is expected:

> '','1','1','21','21','10/10/12','10:30AM','NULL','NULL','pool','NULL','NULL'

Yet when I check the table text type fields literally have the value `NULL` which is not what I want and also int fields show as `0`. If I leave the values blank or as PHP's null then text fields show as empty (or properly `null` as I'd like) yet the ints still show as `0`.

I expect this is only caused due to the way I insert the values indirectly.

Here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE `game`

```
CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Lid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hTeamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vTeamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` text NOT NULL,
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  `hScore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vScore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  `hHoldFor` text,
  `vHoldFor` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO `game` VALUES('','1','1','','','10/09/12','9:30AM','','','pool','winner of pool A','winner of pool B')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't insert `'NULL'`. Remove the single quotes around `NULL`.

Your string

```
'','1','1','21','21','10/10/12','10:30AM','NULL','NULL','pool','NULL','NULL'
```

Should look like

```
'','1','1','21','21','10/10/12','10:30AM',NULL,NULL,'pool',NULL,NULL
```

You should also define a column list whenever making an `INSERT` (ie. `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ...`)

**Edit 1**

I would recommend looking through your `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`

**Edit 2**

After [testing this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a4a5/1), I would still say the problem is with how you're inserting the data.

`(18,1,1,21,21,'10/10/12','10:30AM',NULL,NULL,'pool',NULL,NULL)`

Works.

`('18','1','1','21','21','10/10/12','10:30AM','NULL','NULL','pool','NULL','NULL')`

Does not work: `Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'hScore' at row 1:`

**Edit 3**

Here is an improved version of your class:

```
public static function AddGame($array, $tId)
{
    global $db; // Bring DB into scope

    // Get IDs from particular names
    $locId = $array['fLocation'];

    // Ensure empty values are SQL null
    $hTeamId = empty($array['fHomeTeam']) ? 'NULL' : "'" . $array['fHomeTeam'] . "'";
    $vTeamId = empty($array['fVisitTeam']) ? 'NULL' : "'" . $array['fVisitTeam'] . "'";
    $hScore = empty($array['fHomeScore']) ? 'NULL' : "'" . $array['fHomeScore'] . "'";
    $vScore = empty($array['fVisitScore']) ? 'NULL' : "'" . $array['fVisitScore'] . "'";
    $hHoldFor = empty($array['fHomeHoldFor']) ? 'NULL' : "'" . $array['fHomeHoldFor'] . "'";
    $vHoldFor = empty($array['fVisitHoldFor']) ? 'NULL'  : "'" . $array['fVisitHoldFor'] . "'";

    // Prepare row for insertion
    $row = "$tId,$locId,$hTeamId,$vTeamId,'{$array['fDate']}','{$array['fTime']}',$hScore,$vScore,'{$array['fGameType']}',$hHoldFor,$vHoldFor";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO game (tId, Lid, hTeamId, vTeamId, date, time, hScore, vScore, type, hHoldFor, vHoldFor) VALUES($row)");
    if($stmt->execute()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Non-`NULL` values will be encased in quotes, otherwise they are assigned `NULL`. I've also defined the column list for `INSERT` and excluded `id`, as it's an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Comment: That still doesn't work. I mentioned I tried this at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Can you try the edited version of your string? If this doesn't work, can you reply back with what error you are receiving?

Comment: There's no error, everything inserts which is why I never bothered with defining the column names first as it just adds unneccessary complexity. The problem is the int fields showing zero instead of blank, or (null).

Comment: @Lee can you post what your `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` looks like?

Comment: I posted it. The navicat design view has been lying to me? :S

Comment: @Lee Indeed it has. Glad that helped.

Comment: Hmm I just read that columns are nullable by default, so you need only declare not null. So shouldn't those int columns still allow null?

Comment: @Lee, using the schema you provided, your insert string with quotes does not run. See my edit.

Comment: I see, it must be quotes around the ints being inserted. I didn't realise this incorrect syntax. It does make sense though as it would be attempting a string into an int.

Comment: @Lee, I've added an improved version of your class. Would you mind testing it out?

Answer (score 8):

You are physically setting the value of the wanted `NULL` columns to a string of `'NULL'`

`NULL` != `'NULL'`

If you set your table structure for those columns to `NULL`, you can omit them from your query and they will automatically be `NULL` on insert.

Do this instead:

```
if(!empty($hHoldFor)) $hHoldFor = $array['fHomeHoldFor'];
```

**Update**

I was looking further into your example and there is a second point of failure.

```
$row = ... ",'$hHoldFor','$vHoldFor'";
```

The above line, if you set `$hHoldFor = NULL`, will insert quotes around `NULL`, turning it back into a string of `NULL`.

Try this:

```
if(!empty($hHoldFor)) $hHoldFor = "'{$array['fHomeHoldFor']}'";
...  
$row = ... ",$hHoldFor,$vHoldFor";
```

This removes the single quotes around this value in the QUERY string and adds them to the variable itself.

**Update 2**

Here is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5850/1) using your schema. It returns `NULL` for NULL columns. Can you do an `echo "INSERT INTO`game`VALUES($row)";` and post the output? The issue is PHP is converting the `NULL` to `'NULL`' still somewhere. This will help us get to the bottom of it.

**Update 3**

The issue is just as thought. Your PHP is inserting a blank string, `''`, into your database, which is not a `NULL` value. `NULL` is of a type, `''` is a string with no length.

```
INSERT INTO `game` VALUES('','1','1','','','10/09/12','9:30AM','','','pool','winner of pool A','winner of pool B')
```

Try this:

```
public static function AddGame($array, $tId)
{
    global $db; // Bring DB into scope
    // Get IDs from particular names
    $locId = $array['fLocation'];
    // Ensure empty values are SQL null
    $hTeamId = (strlen($array['fHomeTeam']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fHomeTeam']}'" : 'NULL');
    $vTeamId = (strlen($array['fVisitTeam']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fVisitTeam']}'" : 'NULL');
    $hScore = (strlen($array['fHomeScore']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fHomeScore']}'" : 'NULL');
    $vScore = (strlen($array['fVisitScore']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fVisitScore']}'" : 'NULL');
    $hHoldFor = (strlen($array['fHomeHoldFor']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fHomeHoldFor']}'" : 'NULL');
    $vHoldFor = (strlen($array['fVisitHoldFor']) != 0 ? "'{$array['fVisitHoldFor']}'" : 'NULL');
    // Prepare row for insertion
    $row = "'','$tId','$locId',$hTeamId,$vTeamId,{$array['fDate']}','{$array['fTime']}',$hScore,$vScore,'{$array['fGameType']}',$hHoldFor,$vHoldFor";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `game` VALUES($row)");
    if($stmt->execute()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: I expected this was the case so I tried it without the quotes too, so = null. Which would be PHP's representation of null. This didn't work either. I'm trying your answer now though, thanks.

Comment: Ok so I defined all the variables as null first to avoid the undefined variables errors. The int fields still show as zero.

Comment: There is a second point of failure which i pointed out in update. Take a look.

Comment: That's a great point thanks. If this works, I need not the conditional for checking empty right? As regardless it'll put the value or the null in?

Comment: ok I did as you said but omitted the empty check is it doesn't seem necessary. I revised the code in the original post but those bloody ints still show as zero.

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Comment: Have updated the post with it. There appears to only be default null but no IS NULL despite checking the boxes in design view..

Comment: Reading up on SQL it seems that those columns do actually allow for null judging by the SHOW CREATE TABLE output above?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and your help thus far. I've updated the main post with the echo.

Comment: I'm assuming the ints being inserted shouldn't have quotes around them.

Comment: Updated again. Check the above code. Give it a try.. Also run the echo statement again and see what the query looks like.

Comment: The function returns false, indicating that the statement didn't execute.

Comment: Do you have any error catching to see the error thrown or where the issue exists?

Comment: the issue has been resolved now. Thank you very much for your continued support and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Does you column allows `NULL` values? Check the DDL again maybe you have set the `DEFAULT VALUE` to zero.

When you try to insert `null` value in a column, don not wrap it with single quote. Example

```
INSERT INTO tableName (colName, ColNameB) VALUES (1, NULL)
```

Comment: Yes the check boxes are ticked for allow null and they are also set to default null.

Comment: when you insert the value, do not wrap it with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to display three situations: Case-empty, Case-yes and Case-no. I planned to use null, one and zero. But the null was being saved always as 0. The column i was working accepted null entries but all my nulls was being saved as zeros. 
My solution, was considering Case-empty as zero, Case-yes as the number one and case-no as the number two. It is a workaround but solved the problem.